# Adding an object to my "Cart" in an iPhoneApp leads to entry being added in objects at multiple indexes

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have a peculiar problem which I haven't been able to debug for a while, so Im finally posting it here.

I have an iphone app. It has a Cart Object. Inside the Cart Object are various variables. Among them is an NSMutable Array of "MainDish" Objects. Each "MainDish" Object is itself composed of various variables among them "Sides"(NSMutable Array) being one.

Now the problem is, when the user selects a MainDish, say "AngusBurger" and adds nothing to the sides array, then goes back and immediately selects another "AngusBurger" but to this one adds sides: "fries", "coke, it so happens that both the "AngusBurger" dishes get the sides added to them.

This only happens if the "AngusBurgers" are consecutively ordered, it there is there is another main dish between 2 similar maindishes then this behaviour doesn't happen.....

Im puzzled not sure what is exactly going on......

Here is code inside the ViewController when a sides is picked:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    FoodItem *fm = [Cart.foodItemsArray lastObject];
        [fm.sidesArray addObject:_sidesItem];

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

More Code:

---

Inside ViewController- Adding a fooditem to the Cart:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    Cart = [CartSingleton getSingleton];
    [Cart addFoodItemToCart:selectedFoodItem];
}
```

---

Inside Cart:

```
-(id)init
{
    self.foodItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
}

-(void)addFoodItemToCart:(FoodItem *)itm
{
    numFoodItems++;
    [self.foodItemsArray addObject:itm];
}
```

---

FoodItem:

```
-(id)initWithObjects:(NSString *)_name 
         Description:(NSString *)_description
            Calories:(NSString *)_calories
               Price:(NSString *)_price
           photoPath:(NSString *)_pathToPhoto
            Category:(NSString*)_foodCategory

{
    self.foodName = _name;
    self.foodDescription = _description;
    self.foodCalories = _calories;
    self.foodPrice = _price;
    self.pathToPhoto = _pathToPhoto;
    self.foodCategory = _foodCategory;
    sidesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
    return self;
}
```

---

Adding a Sides Item to a FoodItem: 
(THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA, A SIDE ITEM ADDED TO A FOODITEM GETS ADDED TO A PREVIOUS FOODITEM AS WELL, IF AND ONLY IF THE CONSECUTIVE FOODITEMS ARE THE SAME TYPE)

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    Cart = [CartSingleton getSingleton];
    FoodItem *fm = [Cart.foodItemsArray lastObject];
    [fm.sidesArray addObject:_sidesItem];
}
```

---

SidesItem:

```
-(id)initWithObjects:(NSString *)_name 
         Description:(NSString *)_description
            Calories:(NSString *)_calories
               Price:(NSString *)_price
           photoPath:(NSString *)_pathToPhoto
            Category:(NSString*)_foodCategory

{
    self.sideName = _name;
    self.sideDescription = _description;
    self.sideCalories = _calories;
    self.sidePrice = _price;
    self.pathToPhoto = _pathToPhoto;
    self.sideCategory = _foodCategory;

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code how ordering is done?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. When you say ordering what do you mean? The reason I ask is the code is scattered throughout my project, I want to understand exactly what should I post?

Comment: Ok, I'd like to see the part when you actually put something in your cart and what it is.

Comment: just edited my post above with more code. Sorry about the messyness..... the formatting is hard on this site.....

Comment: Actually it is pretty simple :) I helped a bit. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I've got that special feeling that you are adding references to the same object to your cart array instead of creating new instances of an item and side dishes. Can you dump your array of orders and see with `NSLog(@"%p", object)` if the two AngusBurgers have the same memory address?

Comment: Genius...... Thats exactly what it was........Thanks a bunch man.....Now I gotta spend a few hours fixing this.....")

Comment: You should type something in the "Answer" so I can give you an acceptance rating....

Comment: You are welcome, and here yo go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add references to your cart of the "menu" object, you've got to create copies of it.

Comment: Yeah, I have to fix this at a bunch of places..... after I finish classes today....... thanks for your help......